# Is there a way to preform a belongsToThrough (and is it possible to sort on it)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Given the following example:

**Post**

```
- id
- name
- user_id (FK to class User)
```

**User**

```
- id
- name
- rank_id (FK to class Rank)
```

**Rank**

```
- id
- name
```

Is it possible to make a query with an `orderBy` on `user.rank.name`?

```
$posts = Post::query()
    ->with([
        'user:id,name,rank_id',
        'user.rank:id,name'
    ])
    ->orderBy('something with user.rank.name')
    ->orderBy('user.name')
    ->orderBy('name');
```

Comment: Currently I found a temporary solution: adding a `->join('ranks')` and a `->selectRaw('ranks.name as rank')`, so I can execute `->orderBy('rank')->orderBy('user.name')->orderBy('name')`